# How to keep the outline folded every time reopen the markdown file by GVim Voom markdown?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm using GVim Voom plugin for my markdown documents. The outline is good and efficient.

But I want some part of the outline keep folded, especially when I reopen the document, how to do that?

For example, how to keep the "Head-2" part folded all the time? Thanks! (Normally, when reopen the file, the outline status will restore to default)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `:h views-sessions`.

Basically you can save your view with `mkview` before you close your file and then restore with `loadview`. You could automate that with a Autocmd:

```
augroup AutoSaveView
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinLeave *.tex mkview
  autocmd BufWinEnter *.tex silent loadview
augroup END
```

It is also possible to persist the folds in sessions (`:h session`) if you add folds to the sessionoptions: `:set sessionoptions+=folds`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a marker as folding method: `:set foldmethod=marker`. Then enclose the folded section between triple braces `{{{...}}}` (the default value of `foldmarker`). The braces should be commented, for example:

```
text
text
<!-- {{{ -->
folded text
folded text
<!-- }}} -->
text
text
```

Now the lines will be folded each time the file is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your kind answers! But the VOoM plug-in doesn't support view or session to save the tree status.

I found the solution with help of the plugin author, anyone who meet the same problem, you can find the solution here:
https://github.com/vim-voom/vim-voom.github.com/issues/29

Anyway, thanks again for all your answers.